# Connection Between Application and GA4 Properties

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, google-analytics

I am working for a client who has multiple accounts for each country where it is located, within each account there is a GA4 property. On the other hand, the client only has one application for all of countries and when a user opens the app first time she/he must choose the country where he/she is . The idea is that when the user selects the country in App her/his session information go to GA4 property that is located within the account of the selected country.

In summary, I need to the information arrives at GA4 property of the country chosen for the user in the App. I want to avoid that information from all countries reaches a property and that there are properties from other countries that run out of information.

Thank you

Comment: What session information?  Are talking about a web app?

Comment: You'll need to use the GA4 Data and Admin REST APIs (they are both still in beta). There are no built-in or advanced services available in GAS for them as yet. So you'll need to write your own client to make calls to those APIs from GAS (via UrlFetchApp.fetch()).